# Why are Ringo-chan's cheeks always red?

Tags: tropes, daily-lives-of-high-school-boys

In *Danshi Koukousei no Nichijou*, the character [Ringo-chan](http://myanimelist.net/character/54475/Ringo-chan) is the Student Council president of the rival all-girls high school. For some reason, though, her cheeks are always red (as pictured below).

[image: Ringo-chan]

At first, I thought they were temporary (situational blushing), but it seems these red marks are always on her cheeks. What are these?

Comment: I don't have any source about what I claim next: I think that the red cheek reflects her mental age: she is quite oblivious to the danger in the outside world, as shown in one of the episode.

Comment: Ussualy air headed characters are very active/energetic causing them to have a almost permanent red blush on their cheeks. would support @nhahtdh his statment some what

Comment: @Dimitrimx: I'd say the red blush is the blush on the cheek of small children.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[The Blush Sticker trope](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/BlushSticker) is usually used to express childish cheerfulness and/or naivety. In Japan, children are typically depicted with round rosy cheeks.

Ringo is a bit of an airhead, or rather naive, like a child... The Sanada North High Student Council gave her the "childish" nickname "Ringo-chan" for a reason.~

[image: Fried dumplings]

The trope most likely originated from manga where often times it would be easier (and less time consuming) to draw ovals indicating "blushes", rather than shading them in.

[image: Smile~] [image: Ed] [image: Happy!] [image]

Comment: "*Less time consuming to draw ovals indicating "blushes" than shading them in*" &ndash; Interestingly, there are times when Ringo has both the blush "sticker" and real blush. It makes it look very odd.

Answer (score 8):

Further to Krazer's answer, *ringo* in Japanese means *apple*. I found out recently that the rosy parts of the cheeks are called the [**apples** of the cheeks](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/87864/23608). Ringo-chan's nickname might have come about for similar reasons.